# Yii2 role management with rbac and database storage

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii-extensions, rbac

I want to learn Yii2 membership and use Yii to store and retrieve roles using a database.

I have read [Security Authorization](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html) and [How to add role to user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21308423/how-to-add-role-to-user-yii2) and [Does Anyone Have A Working Example Of Rbac?](http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/49104-does-anyone-have-a-working-example-of-rbac/) and also try using the [yii2-admin](http://www.yiiframework.com/extension/yii2-admin) extension and tried to understand how Yii manages user roles but I can't find any working samples or simple step by step examples.

Please guide me and tell me the simplest solution.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Implementing a role based access control is a very easy process and you can even load your roles from the database if you want.

Step1: Creating necessary tables in the database [ You can also apply migrations with console command `yii migrate` instead of step 1 ]

The first step is to create necessary tables in the database.Below is the sql you need to run in the database.

```
drop table if exists `auth_assignment`;
drop table if exists `auth_item_child`;
drop table if exists `auth_item`;
drop table if exists `auth_rule`;

create table `auth_rule`
(
`name` varchar(64) not null,
`data` text,
`created_at` integer,
`updated_at` integer,
    primary key (`name`)
) engine InnoDB;

create table `auth_item`
(
`name` varchar(64) not null,
`type` integer not null,
`description` text,
`rule_name` varchar(64),
`data` text,
`created_at` integer,
`updated_at` integer,
primary key (`name`),
foreign key (`rule_name`) references `auth_rule` (`name`) on delete set null on update cascade,
key `type` (`type`)
) engine InnoDB;

create table `auth_item_child`
(
`parent` varchar(64) not null,
`child` varchar(64) not null,
primary key (`parent`, `child`),
foreign key (`parent`) references `auth_item` (`name`) on delete cascade on update cascade,
foreign key (`child`) references `auth_item` (`name`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine InnoDB;

create table `auth_assignment`
(
`item_name` varchar(64) not null,
`user_id` varchar(64) not null,
`created_at` integer,
primary key (`item_name`, `user_id`),
foreign key (`item_name`) references `auth_item` (`name`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine InnoDB;
```

Step2: Setting up the config file

Now you can set up the config file to use the authmanager as `DbManager`. This is done by adding the following lines to the components section of your config file

```
     'authManager' => [
                           'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
                           'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
          ],
```

Step3: Adding and assigning roles.

Now you can add roles by simply writing the following code to your corresponding controller.

```
    use yii\rbac\DbManager;
    $r=new DbManager;
    $r->init();
    $test = $r->createRole('test');
    $r->add($test);
```

And you can assign it to the users by

```
    $r->assign($test, 2);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Comment: Thanks Dency, but I have two question:

**1.**Is table structure convention based or it's your suggestion??

**2.**Is it possible to config role management (create table, createRole & assign role ) with migration??

Comment: Please refer to the updated rbac tables at https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/framework/rbac/migrations/

Comment: Thanks Dency.
All things worked except last step (Step3: Adding and assigning roles) I got error on call save method after createRole method:
Calling unknown method: yii\rbac\DbManager::save()

Comment: @b.cyclops..sorry I am using Yii2 alpha version. Please see my updated answer

Comment: You may refer to this link for more details.https://github.com/yiisoft/yii2/blob/master/docs/guide/security-authorization.md#building-authorization-data

Comment: Thanks it's work great and I understand RBAC from your answer.

Comment: Hello, can you explain: need I add foreign key user_id to 'auth_assignment' table?

Comment: and do prefix to each table like tbl_auth_assignment

Comment: The step 1 can be replaced by `./yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations/`

Answer (score 7):

Updated link from official docs: http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

If you are working with database you have to add authmanager to your application components:

```
return [
// ...
'components' => [
    'authManager' => [
        'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
    ],
    // ...
],
```

];

And then execute a migration:

```
yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations
```

It will create automatically the required tables in your database. Now you can access the AuthManager via

`yii migrate --migrationPath=@yii/rbac/migrations`

Comment: Link only answers are not welcomed on Stack Overflow. It will be better if you include essential part of this article.

Comment: This answer is much better.

Comment: For the basic app it needs to be added to 2 locations then only it will work `console.php` & `web.php`