# How should I create guest account pages on my website?

Tags: php, html, yii

In my website I want to allow users to view some of the features by using a guest account. The guest account would see much of the same information as a regular user but some things will be limited.

What would be a good approach, programming wise, to this problem?

1. I copy paste the exact pages that a user would normally have to different .php files, example: `guestProfile.php`. Then I manually remove the buttons or information a guest would see.
2. I add a bunch of checks on my views such as:

   ```
   if(userIsGuest) 
     // then hide info.
   ```
3. Another solution.

What makes the most logical sense in terms of software engineering? Please try to quantify your answer instead of using opinion.

Comment: Second option should be used rather creating a new file..

Comment: i guess if you have that need, your site is most probably closed to some logged in people. in that case I also presume you have some kind of user roles groups, at least for "normal users" and "admins" with different set of access rights. I would then just make a "guest" group and set up specific rights for it...

Comment: 2nd solution is the choice with which you should carry on...!!! and try to use RBAC ...  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554712/yii2-role-management-with-rbac-and-database-storage

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Abstraction is your friend. Rather than stuffing your views with conditionals, you should pass your views any sub-views you wish to be included in the output. Your view doesn't need to know the inner workings of these sub-views, and you can swap them out depending on whether the user is a normal user or a guest user.

Here's a simplistic example:

```
class View {
    /** Does some view stuff... */

    public function addSubview($name, Subview $subview) {
        //store subviews to be used in the template
    }
}

/** 
 * Somewhere in a controller far far away...
 */
class GuestController extends Controller {
    /** Does some controllery stuff... */

    public function exec() {
        //..
        //prepare the view
        $this->view->addSubview('toolbar', $guestToolbarSubview);
    }
}
```

Comment: That is interesting. Can you explain this a bit more?

Comment: Just added an example ;-)

Answer (score 0):

In that case it is better to make the checks (Solution 2). This stays true to the DRY (Don't Repeat Yourself) principle. It keeps your code less redundant and you are less likely to forget to copy changes to your second version of the code.

Comment: Not exactly DRY if your wrapping the same condition around lots of similar code all over the place. Also promotes tight coupling and low cohesion.

Answer (score 0):

Try to keep common code in separate php file and include that file wherever required.