# Yii2 RBAC implementation using DBManager assignment rule fail

Tags: php, sql-server, yii2-advanced-app, rbac

I'm trying to implement RBAC using DBManager in my Yii2 advanced application.
I've read about RBAC in several source and implement RBAC like in https://yii2-cookbook.readthedocs.io/security-rbac/ but it doesn't work. Here is my code.

in the main.php under common/config

```
    return [
    'vendorPath' => dirname(dirname(__DIR__)) . '/vendor',
    'components' => [
        'cache' => [
            'class' => 'yii\caching\FileCache',
        ],
        'authManager' => [
            'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
        ],
    ],
];
```

in RbacController.php under console/controllers

```
namespace console\controllers;

use Yii;
use yii\console\Controller;

class RbacController extends Controller {
public function actionAssign($role, $username) {
       $user = User::find()->where(['username' => $username])->one();
        if (!$user) {
            throw new InvalidParamException("There is no user \"$username\".");
        }
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
        $asrole = $auth->getRole($role);
        if (!$asrole) {
            throw new InvalidParamException("There is no role \"$role\".");
        }
        $auth->assign($asrole, $user->id);
            }
}
```

the migration file

```
use yii\db\Migration;

class m160616_092939_rbac_init extends Migration
{
    public function up()
    {
       $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
       //add permission
        $manageGivenTable = $auth->createPermission('manageGivenTable');
        $manageGivenTable->description = 'Manage and Generate Given Table ';
        $auth->add($manageGivenTable);

        //add permission
        $manageUsers = $auth->createPermission('manageUsers');
        $manageUsers->description = 'Manage users';
        $auth->add($manageUsers);

        //add role. dan ngasih tahu kalau yang tergabung di sbr dapat memanage given tabel
        $sbr = $auth->createRole('sbr');
        $sbr->description = 'Tim SBR BPS HQ';
        $auth->add($sbr);
        $auth->addChild($sbr, $manageGivenTable);

        //add role dan ngasih tahu kalau admin dapat memanage user dan sekaligus mewarisi sifat-sifat sbr
        $admin = $auth->createRole('admin');
        $admin->description = 'Web Administrator, Editor, and Developer';
        $auth->add($admin);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $sbr);
        $auth->addChild($admin, $manageUsers);
    }
```

And I try it in about page. in the controller file, I add

```
'actions' => ['about'],
'allow' => true,
'roles' => ['manageUsers'],
```

NOTE: may be this info is needed

- I use MS SQL Server DB
- [The auth_item table and auth_item_child table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRoQp.jpg)
- other auth table is empty.
- Sorry for bad english.

Can you help me,please?
**Edit**: I've implement role assign using command prompt something like this

```
yii rbac/assign admin adminname
```

in the future, I want to assign user role via admin panel.

Comment: another source I've read : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554712/yii2-role-management-with-rbac-and-database-storage and http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Comment: please explain your error

Comment: the error is the about page can't be access by anyone. admin can't acces it, sbr can't acces it, and unauthorized user can't access it too. I think the role is not assign properly. may be there is something missing when assign the role?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the RbacController.php I add

```
use common\models\User;
```

and it work fine.

Answer (score 0):

the role seems not to assigned. Try to add this

```
try {
    $info = $auth->assign($asrole, $user->id);
    VarDumper::dumpAsString("Role has been assigned ".$info);
} catch (Excpetion $e) {
    VarDumper::dumpAsString("Exception:".$e);
}
```

Comment: where should I put it? **Edit:** I've assign role via command prompt, something like  `yii rbac/assign admin adminname`but nothing changed.