# Yii2 rbac Role assignment is throwing error on signup

Tags: php, yii2, rbac

[image]I am trying to assign a role named 'admin' (already present in auth_item table in database) during signup in yii2. signup() is present inside SignupForm model in common models.

```
$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
$authorRole = $auth->getRole('admin');
$auth->assign($authorRole, $user->getId());
```

but it is throwing an error at vendor\yiisoft\yii2\rbac\DbManager.php as Trying to get property 'name' of non-object .

```
 public function assign($role, $userId)
    {
        $assignment = new Assignment([
            'userId' => $userId,
            'roleName' => $role->name,
            'createdAt' => time(),
        ]);
.....
}
```

this is the function where the error is getting triggered

Comment: Show your RBAC controller where you create `roles` and assign permissions.

Comment: Check if $role is an Object

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco i have not yet touched RBAC controller . Am directly creating the role in database . I am following the steps what they have written in official Yii2 documents

Comment: @SumithChalil This may be helpful : https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/guide/2.0/en/security-authorization#using-migrations, I think you have to initially create roles and permissions before to use them.

Comment: I have already gone through all those steps , not working .

Comment: It works for me: `$auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
        $auth->revokeAll($user->getId());
        $authorRole = $auth->getRole('user');
        $auth->assign($authorRole, $user->getId());`

Comment: @SergheiLeonenco still the error exists. I think the problem is with some missing configuration .

Answer (score 0):

Implementing a role based access control is a very easy process and you can even load your roles from the database if you want.

> Step1: Creating necessary tables in the database [ You can also apply
> migrations with console command yii migrate instead of step 1 ]

The first step is to create necessary tables in the database.Below is the sql you need to run in the database.

```
drop table if exists `auth_assignment`;
drop table if exists `auth_item_child`;
drop table if exists `auth_item`;
drop table if exists `auth_rule`;

create table `auth_rule`
(
`name` varchar(64) not null,
`data` text,
`created_at` integer,
`updated_at` integer,
    primary key (`name`)
) engine InnoDB;

create table `auth_item`
(
`name` varchar(64) not null,
`type` integer not null,
`description` text,
`rule_name` varchar(64),
`data` text,
`created_at` integer,
`updated_at` integer,
primary key (`name`),
foreign key (`rule_name`) references `auth_rule` (`name`) on delete set null on update cascade,
key `type` (`type`)
) engine InnoDB;

create table `auth_item_child`
(
`parent` varchar(64) not null,
`child` varchar(64) not null,
primary key (`parent`, `child`),
foreign key (`parent`) references `auth_item` (`name`) on delete cascade on update cascade,
foreign key (`child`) references `auth_item` (`name`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine InnoDB;

create table `auth_assignment`
(
`item_name` varchar(64) not null,
`user_id` varchar(64) not null,
`created_at` integer,
primary key (`item_name`, `user_id`),
foreign key (`item_name`) references `auth_item` (`name`) on delete cascade on update cascade
) engine InnoDB;
```

> Step2: Setting up the config file

Now you can set up the config file to use the authmanager as DbManager. This is done by adding the following lines to the components section of your config file

```
 'authManager' => [
                       'class' => 'yii\rbac\DbManager',
                       'defaultRoles' => ['guest'],
      ],
```

> Step3: Adding and assigning roles.

Now you can add roles by simply writing the following code to your corresponding controller.

```
use yii\rbac\DbManager;
$r=new DbManager;
$r->init();
$test = $r->createRole('test');
$r->add($test);
```

And you can assign it to the users by

```
$r->assign($test, 2);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-security-authorization.html

Same answer has been provided here: [Yii2 role management with rbac and database storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24554712/yii2-role-management-with-rbac-and-database-storage)

Comment: I have made same rearrangements after reading your answer 
$r=new DbManager;
        $r->init();
        $test = $r->createRole('admin');
        $auth = Yii::$app->authManager;
        $auth->assign($test, $user->getId());  and it is working fine

Comment: if i use createRole instead getRole it is working as expected. But how ?

Comment: because `initially` you do not have this role. Check right now DB you have to find that there is a role `admin` and user associated with this role. Now you can call getRole() to get a role which is already existing. That is why we use console command to create initially roles and permissions, and only after that we apply this roles or permissions to the users.

Comment: No . the role was there before . Have you checked my code in above comments? am not saving it to database .Just simply added a createRole line and after that directly am assigning a user to that role . Means still getRole is not working .

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem, the reason is because `getRole()` method returns `null` as you can see in your app.log file `yii\rbac\DbManager->assign(NULL, 1222049)`

---

SOLUTION

Use `$auth->getPermission('admin')` instead of `$auth->getRole('admin')`